# how to fix 401 unauthorized error for update blogger usin api-3 and OAuth-2.0

Tags: javascript, oauth-2.0, blogger

I'm trying to update a post in a blog made using blogger by using a javascript code, I have everything done as the documents said using OAuth2 but I still get response "401 Unauthorized" I don't know what is wrong in this code? 
*Note:* I already made the signIn code and it's working..

```js
var user = GoogleAuth.currentUser.get();
if (user.Zi!=null){TheToken="Bearer " + user.Zi.access_token;} 

$.ajax
      ({
        url: 'https://www.googleapis.com/blogger/v3/blogs/355327149591714411/posts/7690459698185134878',
        type: 'put',
        Authorization: TheToken,
        contentType: 'application/json',
        data:
        {
          'kind': 'blogger#post',
          'id': '7690459698185134878',
          'blog': {'id': '355327149591714411'},
          'url': 'https://www.wmccoregon.org/2019/04/data-of-settings.html',
          'selfLink': 'https://www.googleapis.com/blogger/v3/blogs/355327149591714411/posts/7690459698185134878',
          'title': 'Data of Settings',
          'content': DataToUpdate
        },
        success: function(data)
        {
          AdminData(vReadSettings,0,0);
        },
        error: function(xhr)
        {
          alert("An error occured: " + xhr.status + " " + xhr.statusText + " " + xhr.responseText);
        }
      });
```

Comment: https://developers.google.com/identity/sign-in/web/reference

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure you're actually passing the bearer token in the headers properly?

As far as I know, `Authorization` isn't an option for `jquery.ajax` (unless you're extending it somewhere). If you're using a bearer token, the string you're creating looks correct, but you need to pass it in the `Authorization` header.

Something like:

```
$.ajax
  ({
    url: 'https://www.googleapis.com/blogger/v3/blogs/355327149591714411/posts/7690459698185134878',
    type: 'put',
    headers: {
      "Authorization": TheToken
    },
  });
```

Comment: thanks for your reply ... 
I tried your idea..when I used headers (with s) it gave me "400 bad request" however whenI tried without the s "header" it back to the original problem.. "401 Unauthorized.. the problem is that ajax is the only way i know to submit http request.. i don'tknow what else i can try and how??

Comment: What are the documents you're working from that you mention in the question? Can you link them?

Comment: google documentations ..and it's really sucks :( i spend 3 weeks trying this and that and decoding their mysteris and puzzels and solved many problems unitl i reached here to this problem... but couldn't find any more help when it come to this last problem !!
this is a link for one of the documentations i'm talking about:
https://developers.google.com/blogger/docs/3.0/using

Comment: Okay. As a starting point, to isolate where the issue is, are you able to use a cURL request or an API client tool like PostMan to make a successful request to the blogger backend with your Authorization token? That would help narrow down whether there is a problem with your request code or whether the token itself is bad.

Comment: I never used them before.. but i got your point.. i'll read about them and try that then we will see :) .. if you have any link or resource that's short and direct about cURL, or if you can write me an example how the command should be or looks like, then i'll be very thankful :)